# Method that requires an Array with >2 items

Tags: c#, geometry

I'm working with Shapes. As we all know, shapes are composed of lines 3 or more lines. One with less than 3 isn't possible.

Is it possible to prevent instantiation of the Polygon class if it has less than 3 Line arguments?

```
public partial class Polygon : Control
{
    private Line[] lines;
    public Line[] Line { get { return lines; } }
    public Polygon(Line[] Lines)
    {
        lines = Lines;
    }
}
// Somwhere else in the code...
new Polygon( new Line(new Vector3(), new Vector3()) ) // invalid shape
```

Comment: Just for clarification, is it 2 lines minimum or 3 lines minimum? One of your numbers seems like a typo.

Comment: Sorry yeah, it was a typo. I meant a minimum of 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw an exception:

```
public Polygon(Line[] Lines)
{
    if (Lines.Length < 3)
        throw new ArgumentException("Number of lines must be greater than 3.");

    lines = Lines;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use default values in case of less than 3 lines.
Try to use the unit-vectors as default values.